# How to install Avahi VNC server browser on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, vnc

The default VNC browser on Ubuntu is Remmina. Is there a way to install Avahi VNC server browser? This is for consistency sake. Another Ubuntu server has Avahi VNC server browser and TigerVNC. I am trying to view the installation of an embedded linux OS that's that connected to my Ubuntu server.

Comment: I don't know exactly what Avahi VNC Server is, but maybe try this https://morioh.com/p/430c8816d62c

Answer (score 0):

APP ubuntu Focal security
https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/net/avahi

File sharing
NFS

If you have an NFS share set up, you can use Avahi to be able to automount them in Zeroconf-enabled browsers (such as Konqueror on KDE and Finder on macOS) or file managers such as GNOME/Files.

Create a .service file in /etc/avahi/services with the following contents:

/etc/avahi/services/nfs_Zephyrus_Music.service

NFS Music Share on %h
  
    _nfs._tcp
    2049
    path=/data/shared/Music

The port is correct if you have insecure as an option in your /etc/exports; otherwise, it needs to be changed (note that insecure is needed for macOS clients). The path is the path to your export, or a subdirectory of it. For some reason the automount functionality has been removed from Leopard, however a script is available. This was based upon this post.
Samba

With the Avahi daemon running on both the server and client, the file manager on the client should automatically find the server.
Vsftpd

You can also auto-discover regular FTP servers, such as vsftpd. Install the vsftpd package and change the settings of vsftpd according to your own personal preferences (see this thread on ubuntuforums.org or vsftpd.conf(5)).

Create a .service file in /etc/avahi/services with the following contents:

/etc/avahi/services/ftp.service

FTP file sharing
  
    _ftp._tcp
    21

The FTP server should now be advertised by Avahi. You should now be able to find the FTP server from a file manager on another computer in your network. You might need to enable #Hostname resolution on the client.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be simple. avahi daemon service was already running. From the software store, I just had to install Avahi VNC server browser and TigerVNC.